# What can I do with a failed bread?

Tags: bread

So I attempted my first loaf of bread tonight and I blew it.  It's flat and way wide (I tried a free pan loaf).  It's about 2 inches tall and very spongy.  It has roughly the consistency of a corn muffin.  It's vaguely edible, but not very breadlike.

So is there anything culinary I can do with this or should I just chuck it on the compost pile?

Comment: Bread crumbs, or ducks/squirrels.

Answer (score 6):

I'd say stuffing, but if it doesn't taste good, then your stuffing won't taste good. Bread pudding? Blech. Bread crumbs? Maybe. Croutons? I don't know, probably not.

Just write it off to experience, and see if the birds fancy it.

Comment: I was thinking bread pudding, personally.  Or fondue.

Comment: If it's got a crumbly texture, I'd go for the breadcrumbs, then bake them in a low oven to try them out for storage.  Feed the rest to the birds.

Answer (score 2):

slice it very thinly, brush it with olive oil, and bake it in the oven at 250 degrees until very dry. Makes great crackers. Sprinkle the olive oil with garlic salt or other herbs.

Comment: Or make croutons -- cube it, heat up a pan of oil with some herbs and garlic, then saute the bread cubes, then spread in a sheet pan to bake in a low oven to dry out.  (this works any time you have a lot of extra bread, as drying it out lets you hold it for weeks)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use or eat my failed baking experiments, and chalk it up to experience, trying to pinpoint where I went wrong so I can do better next time. Even if they don't come out picture-perfect, they are always edible!